# retrieve data attribute from vue.js into jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I need to retrieve data-src attribute from the following line which is done in vue.js:

```
 <img id="some_id" :data-src = "some_path">
```

in order to put it into variable in jquery:

```
var imgSrc = $("img:data(src)");
```

but it does not work. What do I do wrong. I am completely new to vue.js, jquery. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $("#some_id").attr(":data-src");    try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `v-bind:data-src`:

```
v-bind:data-src="some_path"
```

Retrieve the `data_src` value (as per  `Mars.Tsai` comment):

```
var imgSrc = $("#some_id").attr("data-src");
```

Comment: Is $("#some_id").data("src") not possible?

Comment: No, it would return undefined.